# Rounding off decimals in datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have a data table and I have a footer which displays the sum of every column. Although the values above the footer are rounded to two decimal places, some of the values in the footer are not rounded to two decimal places.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXN7x.jpg) My javascript for footercallback:

```
"footerCallback": function(row, data, start, end, display) {
        var api = this.api();

        api.columns('.sum', {
          page: 'current'
        }).every(function() {
          var sum = this
            .data()
            .reduce(function(a, b) {
              var x = parseFloat(a);
              var y = parseFloat(b);
              return x + y;
            }, 0);
          console.log(sum); //alert(sum);
          $(this.footer()).html(sum);
        });
      }
```

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toFixed(2);`For reference look here -[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
.reduce(function(a, b) {
              var x = parseFloat(a);
              var y = isNaN(parseFloat(b))?0:parseFloat(b);
              let result=x + y;
              return result.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. How to neglect "Nan" in the footer for the column Brand?

Comment: You can use isNan() function to check whether its a number or not and return 0 if it is,I have updated my answer @vicky

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Shubh. Do have any idea why the footer is not properly aligned with the columns?

Comment: Cool ,accept the answer if it worked for you @vicky,you might want to try manual css to make it work

Comment: You should check if `b` is `NaN` not the `result`.

Comment: @Titus ,any way it wont make any difference as such as he is accumulating the column value and brand is string so before or after won't be a much difference

Comment: It will, it will reset the total every time a `NaN` value is encountered.
This is a reduce function, `a` is the accumulator (the total at any given point).

Comment: Yes ,I guess you were right @Titus updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function to only get two decimal digits

```
 function (data, type, full) {
         return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
    }
```